# AS3 how to access variables and to set their values using a loop

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, dynamic, set

I have a list of variable (a1 to a4), and I want to use a for loop to access all of them and to set their values.
How to do that in AS3?

```
var a1:Number = 0;
var a2:Number = 0;
var a3:Number = 0;
var a4:Number = 0;

// the primitive way
function setAllToFive():void{
                a1 = 5;
                a2 = 5;
                a3 = 5;
                a4 = 5;
}

// the smart way
function setAllToFiveAlt():void{
                for (var i:uint = 1; i<5; i++){
                  // how to get all the variables in one line ??

                }             
}
```

How to get all the variables in one line?

Thanks,
Ran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use the square bracket notation with a string to refer to a property/variable name:

```
function setAllToFiveAlt():void
{
    for (var i:uint = 1; i<5; i++)
    {
        this["a" + i] = 5;
    }             
}
```

Note that we are using the `+` operator to concatenate the string "a" with the integer `i`, it calls the `toString()` method on the integer automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have four fixed variables you can also go:

```
//define multiple variables on 1 line
var a1:Number, a2:Number, a3:Number, a4:Number;

// set the value of all the variables on 1 line
a1 = a2 = a3 = a4 = 5;
```